# Firebase cloud function doesn't log correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm running a pubsub scheduled function on firebase functions which run every two mintues.
I try to log the events collected by the snapshot loop but something doesn't go properly.

```
exports.check_event_ended_notification = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun((context) => {
        let default_lineup = "default";
        let events = [];

        return admin.database().ref("Events").once('value')
            .then(snapshot => {
                console.log(("EVENTS number : " + snapshot.numChildren()));
                snapshot.forEach(event_snapshot => {
                    let event_key = event_snapshot.key;
                    let event = event_snapshot.val();
                    events.push(event_key);
                    console.log("EVENT_UID : " + event_key);
                    console.log(("EVENTS : " + events));
                    // iterate through all events and check if they're marked as ended
                    // if not, check if ended
                    let event_status = event[['ended_status']];
                    if (event_status === '0') {
                        // get event date
                        let event_day = event[['date']]['0'];
                        let event_month = event[['date']]['1'];
                        let event_year = event[['date']]['2'];
                        let event_full_date = event_year + "-" + event_month + "-" + event_day;
                        // get today date
                        let today = new Date();
                        let today_day = today.getDate();
                        let today_month = (today.getMonth() + 1);
                        let today_year = today.getFullYear();
                        let today_full_date = today_year + "-" + today_month + "-" + today_day;
                        //create date objects to compare
                        let event_date = new Date(event_full_date);
                        let today_date = new Date(today_full_date);

                        // if event date is in the past
                        // check to see if its marked as ended.
                        if (event_date.getTime() < today_date.getTime()) {
                            console.log("EVENT : past event :  " + event_key);
                            if (event[['ended_status']] === "0") {
                                console.log("EVENT : ended 0  :  " + event_key);
                                //mark as ended
                                // admin.database().ref("Events/"+event_key+"/ended_status").set("1");
                                //create notifications for participation artists
                                for (let artist_key in event[['lineup']]) {
                                    console.log("ARTIST before: " + artist_key);

                                    if (artist_key !== default_lineup) {
                                        console.log("ARTIST after: " + artist_key);

                                        let approved_invitation = event[['lineup']][artist_key]['approved_invitation'];
                                        let handshake_status = event[['lineup']][artist_key]['handshake_status'];
                                        let quit = event[['lineup']][artist_key]['quit'];
                                        let removed = event[['lineup']][artist_key]['removed'];
                                        let event_publish_status = event[['publish_status']];
                                        let owner_uid = event[['owner_uid']];

                                        if (approved_invitation === '1' && handshake_status === '1' && quit === '0' && removed === '0' && event_publish_status === '1') {
                                            return admin.database().ref("Notifications/" + artist_key + "/" + owner_uid + "/" + event['uid']).push({
                                                notification_type: "ended",
                                                seen_status: "0",
                                                timestamp: new Date().getTime()
                                            })
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return null;
                })
            })
    }
```

while the numChildren() log at the beginning show there are 4 children under the snapshot (which is correct), the foreach() method seems to run only twice, collecting the first two children and adding them to the "events" list.

and the logs stop after this:

```
2020-07-29T14:22:00.593Z ? check_event_ended_notification: EVENTS number : 4
2020-07-29T14:22:00.593Z ? check_event_ended_notification: EVENT_UID : 3853c2db-f31a-4f46-8c1b-740ca4e3407b
2020-07-29T14:22:00.593Z ? check_event_ended_notification: EVENTS : 3853c2db-f31a-4f46-8c1b-740ca4e3407b
2020-07-29T14:22:00.594Z ? check_event_ended_notification: EVENT_UID : 4253c2db-f31a-4f46-8c1b-740ca4e3407s
2020-07-29T14:22:00.594Z ? check_event_ended_notification: EVENTS : 3853c2db-f31a-4f46-8c1b-740ca4e3407b,4253c2db-f31a-4f46-8c1b-740ca4e3407s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correctly managing the life cycle of your Cloud Function. As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), you need to "resolve functions that perform asynchronous processing (also known as "background functions") **by returning a JavaScript promise**".

Also, in a Cloud Function, it is not recommended to use the `on()` method, which sets a listener, but the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) one, which "listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then stops listening.".

So the following should do the trick:

```
exports.check_event_ended_notification = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun((context) => {
    let default_lineup = "default";
    let events = [];

    return admin.database().ref("Events").once('value')  // Note the return here
        .then(snapshot => {

            snapshot.forEach(event_snapshot => {
                let event_key = event_snapshot.key;
                let event = event_snapshot.val();
                events.push(event_key)
                console.log("EVENT_UID : " + event_key);
                console.log(("EVENTS : " + events));
            });
            
            // Do something with events... We don't have enough details
            
            return null;  // Or return a promise

        });

});
```

---

**Update following your comment**

If you want, in the `forEach()`, to write to the database (which is an asynchronous process), you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), in order to return a promise when all the parallel calls to the asynchronous `push()` method are done.

Here is a skeleton of the code, that you should adapt with all the details:

```
exports.check_event_ended_notification = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun((context) => {
    let default_lineup = "default";
    let events = [];

    return admin.database().ref("Events/").once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {

            const promises = [];

            snapShot.forEach(event_snapshot => {
                let event_key = event_snapshot.key;
                let event = event_snapshot.val();
                events.push(event_key)
                console.log("EVENT_UID : " + event_key);
                console.log(("EVENTS : " + events));

                promises.push(

                    admin.database().ref("Notifications/" + artist_key + "/" + owner_uid + "/" + event['uid']).push({
                        notification_type: "ended",
                        seen_status: "0",
                        timestamp: new Date().getTime()
                    })

                );

            });
    
            return Promise.all(promises);   // This returns a promise!!

        });

});
```

Comment: does the 'return null' in the end suppose to come at the end of the forEach loop or after it ?

Comment: I used `return null;` because I have no details of what you really want to do with the `events` array. If after the `forEach()` you call an asynchronous method (e.g. writing the `events` array to another database node) you need to return the promise returned by this method. To get a more precise idea on how it is important to correctly manage the life cycle of your Cloud Function, I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: thanks for the recommendation, this is my first js project so i probably should learn some more.
Also, i edited the post with the full code including your suggestions.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a skeleton of code, that you should adapt with all the details. Also, have a look at the last video I mention in my previous comment, it covers the use of `Promise.all()`

Comment: so if i understand correctly, i need to save any async task like writing to or querying from the database to a list which in the end of the function will be called by returning the promises array ?

Comment: Since you generate the calls to the `push()` method in a `forEach()` loop their number is variable. You need to execute **in parallel** all these calls before sending back one promise. This is the goal of `Promise.all();`. Did you watch the third video?

Comment: Yes, i saw the video and i worked it out.
Thank you very much for all the help.